# Where does the Chrome or Mozilla store the Downloads path in the file system on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox

I download a lot of files everyday from multiple browsers and it becomes a lot of inconvenience if I am trying to locate a file after a few days.. I don't want to go into each browser and change the download location everyday. I was wondering that there must be some file where all these browsers store these download locations. 
I can just write a shell script that would go and edit these files and set a new download location everyday by appending the current to the folder name..

And I don't have to worry about finding files in a huge cluster.

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome, it's stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`.

Within the file, look for `"download"` and then `"default_directory"` within that.

For Firefox: `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<INSERT_PROFILE_NAME>/prefs.js`

There will be a line saying:

```
user_pref("browser.download.dir", "/path/to/download/folder");
```

Change the path to make it whatever you want. This line might not exist if you've never edited your preferences, so you might need to add it in!

Comment: I tried to read that file.. But there was no where mention of the savePath or some other property or object that would indicate that it stores the path of the Downloads folder.

Comment: My apologies, try looking for `"savefile"` instead. I updated my answer with that.

Comment: I had already looked it up but that savefile is the key to the path when you choose to save file manually for e.g. you right click and choose "Save As" then that's the path saveFile stores. Automatic downloads path might be in a different file. Let me look it up and I will post it here.

Comment: Again, my mistake! I updated my answer one last time; try looking for `"download"` then `"default_directory"`